# How to refresh a TableView when data is inserted in the AppDelegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, reload, tableview

To pre-populate my Database for a small Iphone-App I do a check in the **persistentStoreCoordinator** Method in the AppDelegate if the sqlite-file is already there or not. If not I add some data into a table after the db is created. But the data should not directly shown in the RootViewController but in another TableView which can be accessed by pressing a Option in the RootViewController.

The Problem is that the data are saved but are not shown in the TableView. But if terminate and restart the app the data are there.

I have passed the managedObjectContext from my appDelegate to the the RootViewController and from there to the TableViewController. So the managedObjectContext is the same everywhere.

Here is the Code where I pre-populate the DB (in this example just one sample row):

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
if (persistentStoreCoordinator_ != nil) {
    return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
}

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"TestDBApp.sqlite"];

NSString *storePath = [storeURL relativePath];
BOOL noDb = false;

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if( ![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {
    noDb = true;
}

NSError *error = nil;
persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}    

if( noDb) {
    noDb = false;
    [self populateDB];
}

return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
```

}

```
- (void) populateDB {
// Create the fetch request for the entity.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Kunde" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
// Edit the sort key as appropriate.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"oxid" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![aFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

[self insertNewKunde:aFetchedResultsController];

[self saveContext];

[aFetchedResultsController release];
[sortDescriptors release];
[sortDescriptor release];
[fetchRequest release];
```

}

```
- (void)insertNewKunde:(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

// Create a new instance of the entity managed by the fetched results controller.
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [[fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

// If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
[newManagedObject setValue:[[NSDate date] description] forKey:@"oxid"];
[newManagedObject setValue:@"Max" forKey:@"fname"];
[newManagedObject setValue:@"Mustermann" forKey:@"lname"];

// Save the context.
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

}

The managedObjectContext is passed from the AppDelegate to the RootViewController as:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[navigationController topViewController];

rootViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

}

and to the other TableViewController:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
kundenVC = [[KundenViewController alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

}

Can anyone help me or give a hint?

I also tried to reload the tableView through the viewWillAppear-Method. But no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very difficult to guess what is happening but my hunch is that you are not calling **self.populateDB** until the RootViewController is actually created. This means the RootViewController does not see that data because it is not created.
I could be wrong but I guess that your last line in **delegate's awakeFromNib** method is eventually calling **populateDB** through self.managedObjectContext -> persistentStoreCoordinator -> self.populateDB.

Please try to add a line right at the top of **awakeFromNib** looking like this:

```
(void)awakeFromNib {
     NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;

     RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[navigationController topViewController];

     rootViewController.managedObjectContext = context;}
```

This way I hope the your problem is solved because **self.managedObjectContext** will call the getter (- (NSManagedObjectContext)managedObjectContext;) instead of the field. Inside there (if you use the generated code) there is a call to the getter of ** persistentStoreCoordinator** which eventually calls you **populateDB** method.

In case that does not work go ahead and set a breakpoint inside your populateDB. When the debugger stops you should see at the method call stack where you **populateDB** is actually called from and that might help to figure out your problem.

-Andy

Comment: Thank You for your effort. I have not tried your suggestions because of heavy work. But I noticed your answer and will give you a feedback. So I beg for patience. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I tried your suggestions but no effect. Then I did a debug and there I found a hint. When the call-pointer stayed at my populateDB I noticed that the managedObjectContext was still nil. Because of frustration I opened a new project and here I did the following: 1) in persistentStoreCoordinator I did a check up if the sqlite-File is there. When not I set a bool-flag on true. 2) in managedObjectContext I called my populateDB if the flag was true. Now the data are displayed immediately in the called view. Anyhow, I am thanking you Andy for trying to solve the problem. And sorry 4 the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the important part you left out to answer your question. What is [self saveContext] and how are you displaying the records in your table view.

Because your data is saved I assume that the code given here works. The only guess I can make is to use **reset** on the NSManagedObjectContext and then refetch.

BTW I like the "insertNewKunde" which seems to be the new German grammar ;-)

Comment: **saveContext** is the generated method when a new project is created in Xcode with CoreData Framework. The records are displayed like in the Standard Xcode-Template. Without custom cells. Is the same like in the RootViewController of the Standard-Template.

Comment: I tried to to reset the NSManagedObjectContext after the datas has been added (in the **persistentStoreCoordinator**-Method after the **populateDB** has finished). But no effect. Where should I reset the NSManagedObjectContext?

Comment: Perhaps my approach is totally wrong. I would like to know if there are other ways to pre-populate a DB. The issue is that I am able to save data in the db but the tableview where the records are fetched these data are not recognized. This tableView is in a TableViewController which is not directly accessed through the appDelegate. Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: I used my program to create the SQL Lite DB, then looked up the iPhone Simulator Application's folder and took the SQL lite file from there and put it into my application to load. That is how I pre-populated my DB.

Comment: Normally Custom Cells are defined inside the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method and therefore they should come up.

Comment: I am a little bit confused. Do you see the pre-populated records or not (from populateDB)? What I see is that you create the RootViewController before you call "self.managedObjectContext" which would eventually call "populateDB".

Comment: On another note I never used *awakeFromNib* to bootstrap my app. That said reading the doc I saw that you must call [super awakeFromNib] which you did not.

Comment: Well, I was able to see that the data have been saved when I did the following: Started the App on the simlator. At the moment where the view of the ViewController has been showed I looked into the sqlite-File with the Firefox-Addon SQLiteManager. Here I could see that the data were saved. But when I switched to the the other View where the data should displayed the new data were not there.

Comment: I tried your suggestions [super awakeFromNib] and calling the self.managedObjectContext before the RootViewController is created. But I didn't see any changes.